Does convergence in probability implies uniform convergencce in probability?
Let $(F_{n,X})_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of the empirical cumulative distribution function of distribution positive integer-valued distribution $F_{X}$, such that for all $k \ge 1$ we have
$$ F_{n,X}(k) \xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} F_{X}(k).$$
Is it true that
$$ \sup_{k \ge 1} |F_{n,X}(k)-F_{X}(k)| \xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} 0?$$

It does not make sense to talk about cdfs converging in probability.

Yes, what I meant is that $F_{n}(k)$ is a random variable. I change it now into a sequence of empirical cumulative distribution functions.

For a compact set, the result is direct since you have a finite collection of elements. The problem is how you connect for this case.

For positive integer-valued random variables, it is true that pointwise convergence of the cdf implies uniform convergence. This is because, given $\delta>0$, we can pick an integer $k_0$ such that $F(k_0)\geq 1-\delta/2$, and then choose $n_0$ sufficiently large that, for any $n\geq n_0$, we have $|F_n(k)-F(k)|<\delta$ for all $k<k_0$ and $|F_n(k_0)-F(k_0)|<\delta/2$. (Such $n_0$ exist for each $k$ individually and we are only maximising over a finite number $k_0$ of these.)
Now for $k<k_0$ we already have what we want, and for $k\geq k_0$ we have $1\geq F(k)\geq F(k_0)\geq 1-\delta/2$ and $1\geq F_n(k)\geq F_n(k_0)>1-\delta$, so their difference is less than $\delta$.
This can easily be adapted to cover integer-valued variables.
[edit] To deal with empirical cdfs where we only have convergence in probability, pick $\delta,\epsilon>0$ and choose $k_0$ such that $F_X(k_0)\geq 1-\delta/2$ with probability at least $1-\epsilon/2$. Now let $n_0$ be large enough that $|F_{n,X}(k)-F_X(k)|<\delta$ (for $k< k_0$)  and $|F_{n,X}(k)-F_X(k)|<\delta/2$ each hold with probability at least $1-\epsilon/2k_0$. Now all inequalities hold simultaneously, and hence $\|F_{n,X}-F_X\|_\infty<\delta$, with probability at least $1-\epsilon$.

How, do you formally translate this for convergence in probability?

@bnm I answered before seeing your edit. Will edit my answer to include this.
